# Can't get this SQL / PHP query correct, trying to view details according to specific ID

Tags: php, html, sql

Before I show what I have tried, i'll just explain my scenario. I have three tables. Genre, Games, GameGenre.

- Genre = The different game genres (Action, Adventure, Multiplayer)
- Games = The different games (example 1, example 2, example 3)
- GameGenre = the grid and the gaID and also the ggID (genre, game and gamegenreID)

Currently how this works is, firstly you would create a game genre, then add specific games to that genre. So they both have a geID and a gaID.

Now, what I am trying to do is display these according to genre. So that when I choose a genre, only games which have that genre are listed. Hence I have the ggID.

Code:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Genre WHERE gaID == geID = '$ggID'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
    $geID = $row['geID'];
    $gaID = $row['gaID'];
    echo statements here.
}
```

This does not work though, any help please?

Comment: mysql_query is obsolete use the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL

Comment: Is your goal to get all games with a specific genre (eg. all action games)? In that case you need the genre ID (geID), not the ggID

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this ?

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Genre WHERE gaID = '$ggID' AND geID = '$ggID'");
```

Comment: Missed a `=` in the first condition

Comment: sorry what did you mean missed a = in first condition

Comment: it should be `WHERE gaID = '$ggID'` instead of `WHERE gaID == '$ggID'`

Comment: Sorry for late reply was trying to fix error but I get the error undefined variable ggID?

Comment: Also im not entirely sure now what I should echo? or how I should echo the reuslt?

Comment: did you defined `$ggid` ??

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Genre WHERE gaID = geID AND  geID = '$ggID'");
```

SQL is not C++, and = is not an assignment operator, so A = B = C doesn't make sense. And there is not == in SQL.

Comment: Hi tried this but not entirely sure what to echo and I also get the error, undefined index ggID?

Comment: If you don't actually have a field in the database called ggID then you can't echo it from the recordset. You would have to echo it from the PHP variable $ggID or from the geID field of the recordset.